# Is it possible to set description to a disabled text field in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I would like to add a tooltip to a disabled text field.
Do you have any ideas how can I do it?
I'm using Vaadin 6.8.13.
When I select a specific item in combo box, disabled text field will be enabled. Otherwise, text field will be disabled

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code please? What did you try? Thanks.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Did you find a solution?

Comment: I apologize that I'm answering so late but I didn't have time. So, the problem is that my version of Vaadin doesn't support VaadinRequest (see: http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.rc2/docs/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinRequest.html).
I start to think that it is not possible to do it in Vaadin 6. :-(

Comment: Can you see your created components on screen? Can you post some code?

Comment: I can see all components except for tooltip.

Comment: Try wrapping your disabled label in a layout, link In my answer. Ignore the VaadinRequest part.

Comment: I have tried it. Command `this.setContent(layout)` is not working for Vaadin 6. I see that Vaadin 7 is much more sophisticated than older versions.

Comment: Post your code? How are you currently creating components and adding them to the screen.

Comment: I created custom text field with number validator and I added it to the custom layout. There are all components visible and they're working properly. My only problem is that I can't add tooltip to this disabled text field.
Sorry, I can't post my code because it is a company's secret.

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField readonly = new TextField("Read-Only");
readonly.setValue("I am sitting here read only");
readonly.setReadOnly(true);
readonly.setDescription("Not this time Mojojojo");
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why should it not work -- unless you have not even tried it first.

Disable the `TextField` via `setEnabled(false)` and add a description via `setDescription('...')`:

```
@Grapes([
@Grab('org.vaadin.spring:spring-boot-vaadin:0.0.5.RELEASE'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:7.4.4'),
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.4.4'),
])
import org.vaadin.spring.annotation.VaadinUI
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest
import com.vaadin.ui.*

@VaadinUI
class MyUI extends UI {
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent( new TextField().with{
                caption = "I have a Caption"
                value = "And a Value"
                enabled = false
                description = "And have a Description"
                it
        })
    }
}

// spring run vaadin.groovy
```

Comment: Of course I tried `textfield.setEnabled(false)` and then `textfield.setDescription("description")`, but it is not working.
This code you have typed won't help me because I'm using Vaadin 6.8.13.

Comment: @Lenka these are all important informations.  please add them to the question so at least others have a chance to get it right.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that if I don't add tag Vaadin7, it will mean that I'm not using Vaadin 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the label and then putting it inside a layout. Then set that layout's description. The user won't know the difference.

```
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Hello World");
    textArea.setEnabled(false);

    VerticalLayout textAreaWrapper = new VerticalLayout();
    textAreaWrapper.addComponent(textArea);
    textAreaWrapper.setDescription("Some description");

    layout.addComponent(textAreaWrapper);
    this.setContent(layout);
    this.setSizeFull();
```

You could create your own class which extends VerticalLayout and creates a TextArea inside it. That way you don't have to create a layout wrapper each time you just create your "MyTextArea" or whatever you want to call it.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**N.B.**

From your question I had originally thought the following code wouldn't work but it works fine? I haven't tried it in Vaadin 6.8.13 though. I am using Vaadin 7.1.2.

```
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Hello World");
    textArea.setEnabled(false);
    textArea.setDescription("Some description");

    layout.addComponent(textArea);
    this.setContent(layout);
    this.setSizeFull();
```

Comment: you use xGH wisely, interesting

Comment: What? Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i found your solution interesting